# .net mvc 3/4 app pool threads usage with async actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, application-pool

Lets say u have a set amount of maximum threads in your app pool to process web requests for ur mvc application. When an async method is called from within ur SYNCRONIOUS controller action does that use a thread from the set application pool threads or does that spawn a new thread (not from your application pool) to process that async operation?

I know the application is only allowed to run with the allowed amount of threads in the application pool but i wasnt to sure abt the spawning of threads for an async method from within a sycnronious controller action.

Comment: By async action do you mean BeginXXX method call?